# Is there another way to solve this logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$${ x }^{ 3-\log { x }  }=100$$

I couldn't think up of an algebraic way to solve this equation so I resorted to thinking through it logically. Although this led me to the correct solution, I don't think that this method is concrete enough to use. How can I solve this properly?

Steps I took to solve this my way:

$${ x }^{ 3-\log { x }  }=100^{ 1 }\quad or\quad { x }^{ 3-\log { x }  }=10^{ 2 }$$

$$3-\log { x } =1\quad or\quad 3-\log { x } =2$$

$$-\log { x } =-2\quad or\quad -\log { x } =-1$$

$$\log { x } =2\quad or\quad \log { x } =1$$

$$x=100\quad or\quad x=10$$

Comment: your results are ok!

Comment: Your work is NOT OK because you have no ground in assuming x = 100 in the LS of your 2nd ‘or’ (similarly for letting x= 10 in the RS). Furthermore, if those are true, “going through another 3 steps to say that they are true again” is ‘going round and round’.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I guess you are just joking, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the logarithm of left and right side of the equation and you'll get a quadratic equation w.r.t. unknown $\log x$.

Comment: $\log { { x }^{ 3-logx } } =log100\Rightarrow (3-logx)(logx)=2\Rightarrow -(logx)^{ 2 }+3logx-2=0\Rightarrow (logx)^{ 2 }-3logx+2=0\Rightarrow (logx-2)(logx-1)=0\Rightarrow x=100\quad and\quad x=10$

Comment: @Cherry_Developer It should be "or" in last formula. Yep, that's exactly what I've meant :)